# Connecting SMA connector for GNSS & 4G LTE to Modem

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, antenna

A friend and I are developing a device which needs a connection via a Simcom7080G modem to 4G LTE and GNSS. Now, We are embedded software engineers and have some understanding of electronics but we are no electronic engineers.

We searched a lot online but couldn't really find a satisfying answer. We are trying to use simple SMA connectors from the modem to an external antenna. But can't find out how to connect the SMA connectors. Are filters required for example? Or other components in between?

Is it possible to just connect a SMA connector to the correct pins as shown in the following screenshot? (the two thick red traces)

[image]

Now, it is my understanding from what I could find, that the trace needs to be shorter than 1/10th of the wavelenght. Which in turn makes the 50 ohm impedance no issue. Is this true? I believe I calculated it correctly if I say that the traces for 4G LTE should not be longer than 11 mm. GNSS can be even longer. The traces as shown in the picture are shorter, which would make the connection really easy. So easy in fact, that I don't believe it could be this easy.

Any help with how to connect the SMA connectors properly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an account to access the design information at https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM7080G.html? The site isn't letting download without registering. The manufacturers design information should help to identify how to connect the antenna.

Comment: We managed to find this document: https://www.texim-europe.com/Cmsfile/SMM-SIM7080G-Hardware-Design-V1.04-DS-200525-TE.pdf, which describes the connections for the antennas, but  mainly focuses on trace antennas and hardly touches on SMA connectors. From figure 28 we deduced that an SMA connector could be connected the way we did, but we are unsure if that is actually the case.

Comment: Note that the "shorter than 1/10 of the wavelength" rule-of-thumb is generally applied to digital signals and interfaces.  There may be bad effects that affect your RF performance even with trace lengths less than 1/10 lambda.  That's why with RF/microwave designs, we design everything (even vias and wirebonds) to have 50 ohm impedance.

Comment: If you want to use an active GNSS antenna, then will need a [Bias tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee) on the SMA connector to provide power. https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/0/0d/SIM7080X-Cat-M-NB-IoT-HAT-Schematic.pdf contains one example of allowing an active GNSS antenna to connect to the SIM7080G.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to RF signals, nothing would be easy. You are right to be concerned about it.

Have a look at this video: [PCB Antenna - How To Design, Measure And Tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1m8G8MAeUQ)

You don't have to worry about the PCB Antenna part, as you already have an external antenna. But the video explains very well what to consider when you are placing that track from the chip/module to the antenna. You always need an impedance match especially when you are using cheaper PCB materials that could have uncontrolled capacitance. Sometimes, the match filter has a very negligible effect, but if you plan to sell the product, you have to go through it to make sure it does not create interference to the side channels.

There are a couple of tools introduced in that video like [this](https://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm), one that helps for choosing the width and stack layers.

Overall, it will be a very costly process and needs a very expensive tool to do it right. However, you can use those tools to minimize the problem in design by choosing the right track width, ground clearance and stack layer width.